# Matplotlib + Latex: Escrevendo texto nos eixos em português

Tags: matplotlib, ipython-notebook, latex

Vamos do começo, as versões que tenho são:

Ipython: 1.1.0

Matplotlib: 1.3.1

Latex: pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Quero plotar o que está abaixo, numa sessão do Ipython-Notebook

```py
# Using the magic encoding
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

fig_width_pt =  512#246.0               # Get this from LaTeX using 
                                        # \showthe\columnwidth
inches_per_pt = 1.0/72.27               # Convert pt to inch
golden_mean = (sqrt(5)-1.0)/2.0         # Aesthetic ratio
fig_width = fig_width_pt*inches_per_pt  # width in inches
fig_height = fig_width*golden_mean      # height in inches
fig_size =  [fig_width,fig_height]

params = {'backend': 'ps',
          'axes.labelsize': 10,
          'text.fontsize': 10,
          'legend.fontsize': 10,
          'xtick.labelsize': 10,
          'ytick.labelsize': 10,
          'text.usetex': True,
          'figure.figsize': fig_size}
rcParams.update(params)
plt.xlabel(r'$Diâmetro de Agua Doce$')
plt.ylabel('Diametro de Agua Salgada')
plt.title('Distribuicao da Populacao de Salmoes')

alaska_plot_list0 = list(alaska[:,0])
alaska_plot_list1 = list(alaska[:,1])
scatter(alaska_plot_list0, alaska_plot_list1, 
        label="Alaska", color='green', alpha=.5)

canada_plot_list0 = list(canada[:,0])
canada_plot_list1 = list(canada[:,1])
scatter(canada_plot_list0, canada_plot_list1, label="Canada", alpha=.5)
#scatter(alaska[:,0], alaska[:,1], 'o', alpha=.5, label="Alaska")
#scatter(canada[:,0], canada[:,1], 'o', alpha=.5, label="Canada")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
savefig('distribuicao.pdf')
```

Observe essa linha:

```py
plt.xlabel(r'$Diâmetro de Agua Doce$')
```

O que força o uso do acento circuflexo dentro do ambiente LaTeX (observe o parâmetro dentro de 'params': 'text.usetex' = True. Acontece que isso resulta no seguinte erro:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a1d75b5e9ea2> in <module>()
     33 plt.legend()
     34 plt.grid()
---> 35 savefig('distribuicao.pdf')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    559 def savefig(*args, **kwargs):
    560     fig = gcf()
--> 561     return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    562 
    563 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in savefig(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1419             self.set_frameon(frameon)
   1420 
-> 1421         self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
   1422 
   1423         if frameon:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.pyc in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2218                 orientation=orientation,
   2219                 bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
-> 2220                 **kwargs)
   2221         finally:
   2222             if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.pyc in print_pdf(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1950         from backends.backend_pdf import FigureCanvasPdf  # lazy import
   1951         pdf = self.switch_backends(FigureCanvasPdf)
-> 1952         return pdf.print_pdf(*args, **kwargs)
   1953 
   1954     def print_pgf(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.pyc in print_pdf(self, filename, **kwargs)
   2350                                          width, height, image_dpi, RendererPdf(file, image_dpi),
   2351                                          bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore)
-> 2352             self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2353             renderer.finalize()
   2354         finally:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     54         before(artist, renderer)
---> 55         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         after(artist, renderer)
     57 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
   1032         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
   1033         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
-> 1034             func(*args)
   1035 
   1036         renderer.close_group('figure')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     54         before(artist, renderer)
---> 55         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         after(artist, renderer)
     57 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2084 
   2085         for zorder, a in dsu:
-> 2086             a.draw(renderer)
   2087 
   2088         renderer.close_group('axes')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     54         before(artist, renderer)
---> 55         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         after(artist, renderer)
     57 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1103         self._update_label_position(ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2)
   1104 
-> 1105         self.label.draw(renderer)
   1106 
   1107         self._update_offset_text_position(ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     54         before(artist, renderer)
---> 55         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         after(artist, renderer)
     57 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
    545         renderer.open_group('text', self.get_gid())
    546 
--> 547         bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(renderer)
    548         trans = self.get_transform()
    549 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    327                 w, h, d = get_text_width_height_descent(clean_line,
    328                                                         self._fontproperties,
--> 329                                                         ismath=ismath)
    330             else:
    331                 w, h, d = 0, 0, 0

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.pyc in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
   1950             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
   1951             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(s, fontsize,
-> 1952                                                                renderer=self)
   1953             return w, h, d
   1954 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.pyc in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    664         else:
    665             # use dviread. It sometimes returns a wrong descent.
--> 666             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
    667             dvi = dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction)
    668             try:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.pyc in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
    385             return self.make_dvi_preview(tex, fontsize)
    386 
--> 387         basefile = self.get_basefile(tex, fontsize)
    388         dvifile = '%s.dvi' % basefile
    389 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.pyc in get_basefile(self, tex, fontsize, dpi)
    221                      self.get_custom_preamble(), str(dpi or '')])
    222         # make sure hash is consistent for all strings, regardless of encoding:
--> 223         bytes = unicode(s).encode('utf-8')
    224         return os.path.join(self.texcache, md5(bytes).hexdigest())
    225 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x4727a10>
```

Procurando na web e no StackOverflow (inglês) eu encontrei várias formas de tentar colocar esses caracteres pelo matplotlib + LaTeX. Coisas como:

```py
plt.xlabel(u'Diâmetro de Agua Doce')
```

Retornam:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-a1e2e4496433> in <module>()
     33 plt.legend()
     34 plt.grid()
---> 35 savefig('distribuicao.pdf')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    559 def savefig(*args, **kwargs):
    560     fig = gcf()
--> 561     return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    562 
    563 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in savefig(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1419             self.set_frameon(frameon)
   1420 
-> 1421         self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
   1422 
   1423         if frameon:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.pyc in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2218                 orientation=orientation,
   2219                 bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
-> 2220                 **kwargs)
   2221         finally:
   2222             if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.pyc in print_pdf(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1950         from backends.backend_pdf import FigureCanvasPdf  # lazy import
   1951         pdf = self.switch_backends(FigureCanvasPdf)
-> 1952         return pdf.print_pdf(*args, **kwargs)
   1953 
   1954     def print_pgf(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.pyc in print_pdf(self, filename, **kwargs)
   2350                                          width, height, image_dpi, RendererPdf(file, image_dpi),
   2351                                          bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore)
-> 2352             self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2353             renderer.finalize()
   2354         finally:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     54         before(artist, renderer)
---> 55         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         after(artist, renderer)
     57 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
   1032         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
   1033         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
-> 1034             func(*args)
   1035 
   1036         renderer.close_group('figure')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     54         before(artist, renderer)
---> 55         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         after(artist, renderer)
     57 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2084 
   2085         for zorder, a in dsu:
-> 2086             a.draw(renderer)
   2087 
   2088         renderer.close_group('axes')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     54         before(artist, renderer)
---> 55         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         after(artist, renderer)
     57 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1103         self._update_label_position(ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2)
   1104 
-> 1105         self.label.draw(renderer)
   1106 
   1107         self._update_offset_text_position(ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     54         before(artist, renderer)
---> 55         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         after(artist, renderer)
     57 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
    545         renderer.open_group('text', self.get_gid())
    546 
--> 547         bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(renderer)
    548         trans = self.get_transform()
    549 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    327                 w, h, d = get_text_width_height_descent(clean_line,
    328                                                         self._fontproperties,
--> 329                                                         ismath=ismath)
    330             else:
    331                 w, h, d = 0, 0, 0

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.pyc in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
   1950             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
   1951             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(s, fontsize,
-> 1952                                                                renderer=self)
   1953             return w, h, d
   1954 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.pyc in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    664         else:
    665             # use dviread. It sometimes returns a wrong descent.
--> 666             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
    667             dvi = dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction)
    668             try:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.pyc in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
    389 
    390         if DEBUG or not os.path.exists(dvifile):
--> 391             texfile = self.make_tex(tex, fontsize)
    392             outfile = basefile + '.output'
    393             command = self._get_shell_cmd(

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.pyc in make_tex(self, tex, fontsize)
    304             else:
    305                 try:
--> 306                     fh.write(s.encode('ascii'))
    307                 except UnicodeEncodeError as err:
    308                     mpl.verbose.report("You are using unicode and latex, but "

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe2' in position 299: ordinal not in range(128)

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x4613e90>
```

Que é exatamente igual ao erro anterior.

E:

```py
plt.xlabel('Diâmetro de Agua Doce'.decode('utf-8'))
```

Retorna:

O mesmo erro.

Existe alguma forma de usar os caracteres: á, à, é, í, õ, ú e outros acentuados?

Comment: Eu tenho a resposta, mas não posso responder antes de oito horas passadas da postagem da pergunta. =P

Comment: Cara, não consegui rodar seu código aqui, dá erro: `NameError: name 'rcParams' is not defined` -- está faltando a definição da variável `rcParams`.

Comment: @elias Você importou o matplotlib? Não tá no código... =P

Comment: Botei `from matplotlib import *` e agora ele reclamou `plt is not defined`. Eu tô rodando ele no prompt. O que precisa importar pra ele rodar?

Comment: Eu to usando o Ipython-Notebook que importa uma renca de coisas pra mim, pro baixo dos panos.

Comment: Mas tente o seguinte import: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: agora foi `NameError: name 'alaska' is not defined`

Comment: Dica pra quem for testar e sentir falta da definição de "alaska" ou "canada": 
import numpy as np
alaska = np.random.rand(100,2)
canada = np.random.rand(100,2)

Comment: Aqui deu o mesmo erro, tanto com plt.savefig() com plt.show(). O problema apenas é resolvido se desabilitar o usetex. Você tentou usar os caracteres de escape do latex ao invés de acentuação com unicode?

Comment: Aqui funcionou assim: plt.xlabel('Di\^{a}metro de Agua Doce'). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta adicionar outro parâmetro à lista de parâmetros usados anteriormente:

Ao utilizar:

```py
'text.latex.unicode' = True
```

Como abaixo (penúltima linha) nos parâmetros originais:

```py
params = {'backend': 'ps',
      'axes.labelsize': 10,
      'text.fontsize': 10,
      'legend.fontsize': 10,
      'xtick.labelsize': 10,
      'ytick.labelsize': 10,
      'text.usetex': True,
      'text.latex.unicode': True,
      'figure.figsize': fig_size}
rcParams.update(params)
```

A gente resolve o problema sem precisar recorrer a inserção de caracteres como \~{o} ou \'{a}.

O detalhe é que agora as strings tem que ser unicode:

```py
plt.xlabel(u'Diâmetro de Água Doce')
plt.ylabel(u'Diâmetro de Água Salgada')
plt.title(u'Distribuição da População de Salmões')
```

[image: Com Unicode!]

Comment: Limpo e elegante! Sugiro aceitar essa resposta. :)

Answer (score 8):

Se você utilizar os caracteres de escape do latex ao invés do texto em unicode diretamente com acentuação, o problema não ocorre.

Tente trocar as suas strings pelo seguinte:

```py
plt.xlabel('Di\^{a}metro de Agua Doce')
plt.ylabel('Di\^{a}metro de Agua Salgada')
plt.title('Distribui\c{c}\~{a}o da Popula\c{c}\~{a}o de Salm\~{o}es')
```

Aqui o resultado foi assim (note que eu estou utilizando numpy pra gerar valores aleatórios para os dados não incluidos no seu exemplo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]